# Read MySql sequentially on primary key

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any way to read a MySql database sequentially on the primary key? The file contains about 1.5M rows. I do not want to read all of them and ORDER them, just so I can get the first 100 records.

I tried this code but it seems to start at some random location in the middle of the key range:

```
  $query = "SELECT main_key FROM mytable LIMIT 100";
  $table = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
  while ($rec = mysql_fetch_row($table)) 
      echo $rec[0].'<br>';
```

Comment: Dont use mysql_* functions anymore.Use PDO or mysqli_*

Comment: Try `SELECT main_key FROM mytable LIMIT 0,99`

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran That won't guarantee the order. See my answer below.

Comment: Try `$query = "SELECT main_key FROM mytable order by main_key LIMIT 0,99";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL doesn't guarantee an order unless you specify the required order in an ORDER BY clause. To get the first 100 records do this:

```
$query = "SELECT main_key FROM mytable order by main_key LIMIT 100";
```

The database is **very** good at optimising queries, and will use an index if it estimates it is the fastest way to complete the query. Don't try to second guess it: it's probably better at it than you or me.

Comment: Will that cause it to read all 1.5M records, or will it just read 100 records, given that the field is keyed? When I tried that it seemed to hang for ages.

Comment: It should just read the first hundred from the index. However, there might be some reason why it doesn't. You can find out what the server intends to do by using the EXPLAIN command. That might point you at a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want them ordered, then use the ORDER BY clause:

```
SELECT main_key FROM mytable ORDER BY main_key LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"I tried this code but it seems to start at some random location in the middle of the key range"*
>   SELECT main_key FROM mytable LIMIT 100

I wonder if `main_key` is PRIMARY KEY of mytable. I guess MySQL Optimizer choose non-PK index scan.

IMHO you have two possible choices.

### USING FORCE INDEX

I think `FORCE INDEX` forces always use `PRIMARY KEY`.

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT main_key FROM tab_name FORCE INDEX(PRIMARY) LIMIT 10;
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tab_name | index  | NULL          | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL | 13427712 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
```

### Using HANDLER

MySQL has interesting functionality called [`HANDLER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/handler.html). With `HANDLER` you could open certain INDEX (of course PRIMARY supported), and you can get

- `N rows` from start of table
- and next `M rows` from `Nth position`
- or `K rows` from end of table.

So, you don't need to sort, fetching order is guaranteed.

```
-- OPEN HANDLER
HANDLER tab_name OPEN;

-- get first 100 records from PK
HANDLER tab_name READ `PRIMARY` FIRST LIMIT 100;

-- get next 100 records
HANDLER tab_name READ `PRIMARY` NEXT LIMIT 100;

-- get 100 records from End of Table
HANDLER tab_name READ `PRIMARY` LAST LIMIT 100;

-- CLOSE
HANDLER tab_name CLOSE;
```

- pros

  - very fast
- cons

  - This is not ANSI standard
  - You can't specify which columns are retrieved.
  - all columns of table are returned.

Comment: So ORDER BY isn't a choice?

Comment: @Strawberry Good morning, Strawberry. I saw your comment at this time. I agree with other answers. `ORDER BY pk_column` should use PK Index scan without actually sorting. But OP left comment on Mike's answer; *"When I tried that it seemed to hang for ages."* . I guess there are some problem I don't know or OP didn't explain in detail his situation. I think Preceding code snippets in my answer work as we expected.